# No smooth scrolling on Chrome for Ubuntu

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, touchpad, scrolling

I did enable the `#enable-smooth-scrolling` flag in Chrome and rebooted both Chrome and the machine numerous times, but scrolling in Chrome is still just as jumpy. I know it's not hardware issue, as my machine can handle smooth scrolling of huge .pdf documents just fine, but Chrome stutters even on simplest webpage. Is there an additional flag I should enable or perhaps a some touchpad configuration I should make to see Chrome on Ubuntu scrolling just as smooth as on Windows?

Comment: Make sure that disable-threaded-scrolling is not enabled.

Comment: It looks like Chrome 49 (to be released in March 2016) will finally support Smooth Scrolling: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575

Answer (score 0):

While on the flags page, there are two features that you need to enable. An easy way to do this is by searching for Smooth Scrolling. The first is Threshold Composing, enable that, then enable the Smooth Scrolling feature.

Comment: I don't see anything about "Threshold Composing" in the Chrome/Chromium chrome://flags page. Please edit to clarify what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Enabling only "Smooth Scrolling" under chrome://flags/ solved the issue for me. Ubuntu 16.04, google-chrome-stable 63.0.3239.84-1